# Display slideshow of Images and Videos over SSH

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, kodi, omxplayer

**Device**: 3 B Plus

I am trying to create a slideshow of videos / images. The user can select which files he wants to put in the slideshow and this will be shown on a TV. (As an addition, I would also like that it  The problem is that I don't know which package to use. These are the ones I've tried so far:

**Omxplayer** - Problem is that it doesn't support still images.

**fbi** - Seems to be broken. Displays images in a completely random order with wrong time interval.

**feh** - Doesn't work with videos.

**Kodi** - Does it have ability to interact with it over SSH? I didn't see any Action in the documentation that would point to my needs

Comment: I would search for 'digital signage' software. there are several packages out there that are suitable (and even written) for the Pi. BTW: you can interact with Kodi over the network without resorting to SSH. It has a built-in web interface.